# jQuery How to select all nodes text in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="movie">

    Date: 
    <span class="date"> June 12, 1987 </span>

    Título: 
    <span class="title">
        <a class="select_movie" href="#">
            Predator
        </a>        
    </span>

    Director: <span class="director">John McTiernan</span>

    Starring: <span class="starring">Arnold Schwarzenegger</span>

</div>
```

I want all the text nodes in `<div class="movie">`, after the click of a link `.select_movie`

```
$('.select_movie').click(function(){
    ..........
    ..........
});
```

at the end I need to retrieve the value of the nodes to be assigned to a variables, like this:

```
var date = June 12, 1987;

var title = Predator;

var director = John McTiernan;

var starring = Arnold Schwarzenegger;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in order to get each of the values:

```
$('.select_movie').click(function(){
    var movie = $(this).closest(".movie");
    var date = $(movie).find(".date").text();
    var title = $(movie).find(".title .select_movie").text();
    var director = $(movie).find(".director").text();
    var starring = $(movie).find(".starring").text();
});
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/unwgeqce/1/

Comment: Guessing here, but there may be multiple movies on the page.  Perhaps going after the closest .movie would be helpful to the OP?

Comment: It was very useful reply, which I worked was this: 
var title   = $(this).parent('span').parent('div').children('.title').text();

Comment: @user1034380 Your code is correct, but it is very fragile because if the markup changes, the selectors would be incorrect. If you know the classes of the immediate elements you are trying to get, it is better to have the less selectors, the closest to that element, as the code in the response.

Answer (score 0):

something like this for each var:

```
var date = $('.movie').find('.date').text();
```